# Application crashes at [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource

Tags: iphone, path, crash

My Application is crashes in the device at this point,

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource
```

I am giving the path for the pdf here . but at the execution time it is showing that it is not getting path there . and that may be the reason for crashing.

however it is running perfectly on simulator .

i am not able to figure out why is this happening

here is that code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[myArray objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[myArray objectAtIndex:1]];
NSLog(@"array elemt :%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"array elemt 1 :%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:1]);
NSLog(@"path is :%@",path);
NSLog(@"responds to selector mainBundle=%@",[NSBundle respondsToSelector:@selector(mainBundle)]?@"YES""NO");
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

in this log of the path - when i use device it is showing me `nil` and when i use simulator it is showing me the path . and it is showing me that is is crashing on `NSURL` line

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Can you show us what the array element 0 and 1 are? Maybe I can figure out the error from there

Comment: I guess pdf you are searching for doesn't exist in the mainBundle.

Comment: guys .. thanks for looking at it ... found the error .. at other place i had written pdf in pure caps .. it should not be like that there :)

Comment: Can you post outputs of NSLog's "array elemt and array elemt 1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that when something like this works on the simulator, but not on the device, it's likely a problem with the case of the string. Your device is case sensitive but not your computer. Check your string of the file name or the type.

Comment: yes ... you were right ... brondie .. it was the case sensitive prob.. thanks ... accepted and up

Comment: I'd still double check the case. The code looks okay to me, but we need to see what your array objects are. But the bottom line is pathForResource is not finding your resource. If you're positive the case is right, what about trying a clean or deleting the app from the device and starting over? - Edit- Great, glad it worked