# NSBundle returning NULL

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have been using pathForResource for a while but suddenly its giving up on me.
I have added an additional file to my resources called `untitled.obj` and `untitled.mtl`.

[image: copy bundle resources]

And following two lines of code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"untitled" ofType:@"obj"];
NSLog(@"thePath = %@", path);
```

All other *.obj files work fine, except `untitled.obj`.

The output from NSLog is nothing when i use that file, so i assume its unable to find it for some reason.

[image]

The resource is also located in the temp. simulation library:

[image]

Comment: How did you add the new file, and is it included in your target? Select the file in your project and check in the inspector on the right hand side - is your target checked?

Comment: @jrturton, both files are in the target membership for the target. I placed the file in the directory as all the other *.obj files and dragged them into the folder as the others were located inside.

Comment: New update. The resource that i cannot find is also located i the simulation directory, so it makes even less sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the app from your device and reset contents and settings in the simulator. Also delete Derived Data of the project. After you do that, test again and it should work.

Comment: I deleted the app, reset content and settings. Removed the App simulation files. And tried again. Result still the same. What do you mean by "Derived Data"? Thank you!

Comment: Go to the **Organizer**, open the **Projects** tab and select your project. You will see **Derived Data** and a **Delete** button in front if it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct to me.  Have you checked that you haven't accidentally named the file with a trailing space or other invisible character?  Try naming it something entirely different (including changing the extension) and then renaming it back.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the .plist file. There you have the Bundle name and identifier.

Comment: I dont think i understand you entirely. I already have a *.plist file with bundle name/identifier.

Comment: Should not be neccessary, since my target already has initialized the *.plist file.

Comment: Then make sure you have Bundle name, Bundle identifier, Bundle version, Bundle versions string, short, Bundle display name, Bundle OS Type code, Bundle creator OS Type code in your plist. These are created automatically, but maybe something went wrong. My opinion, just make sure the plist contains all the default settings.

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510717/application-crashes-at-nsbundle-mainbundle-pathforresource

Comment: I have taken case sensitive into consideration, but thats not the case.

Comment: then it must not be a bundle problem. try to delete/ rename your file, and them import it by copying it to your project again. It must work like this.